# Game Screeps. Error during simulation. CPU limit reached

Tags: javascript, screeps

I'm going throw Screeps (http://screeps.com/) simulation. I've stick on stage when I need to send worker to harvest resources. So I put code from the tip to the script tab, code is:

```
var creep = Game.creeps.Worker1;    
var sources = creep.room.find(Game.SOURCES);    
creep.moveTo(sources[0]);    
creep.harvest(sources[0]);
```

My creep had started move to source, but then it froze and I got error (light red text) in console:

```
CPU limit reached
```

What I need to do to finish this step and why I'm getting this error?

Comment: your code is fine, the simulation has a 5 second CPU limit. I used the same code without any problems. (make sure you still have a worker: Game.spawns.Spawn1.createCreep( [Game.WORK, Game.CARRY, Game.MOVE], 'Worker1' );)

Comment: @Marco you should make your comment an answer.

Comment: I have the same issue. Seems like a bug to me. The whole game is now frozen.

Answer (score 2):

It's a limitation of the Simulation Room mode. Commit the scripts, refresh the page and start simulating again and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://screeps.com/docs/coding.php):

> Please remember that the exact duration of the execution of your
>   script is limited by the CPU time available in your service plan. In
>   case of exceeding the limit, the script execution will be stopped.
>   **The exception is the Simulation Room where the script execution is always limited by 5 seconds.**

So it seems that your creep can't find anything to harvest within five seconds

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in Internet Explorer 11 (and probably older versions too but I don't have older versions installed).  I would create a creep and everything would be fine and dandy until sometime between moving to and starting to collect from a source at which point the entire thing would freeze.  I think this is just lazy programming because I was able to get everything working by switching to Chrome 39.blah.blah.blah.  If you're not using Chrome I would suggest using it for this game.

Comment: As a web developer and an overall internet user i honestly do not understand why someone would use IE over anything else under their personal laptops.

Comment: The dev tools are so much better on IE!  The Profiler and Memory stuff is much nicer than Chrome.  IE also supports more levels of web workers and I like how it handles touch gestures much better than chrome.  I will say that the console.log(object) is nicer on Chrome than IE.

Comment: That's odd, as I get soo much more use out of dev tools on chrome then any other browser.  To each his own, I guess.